# Calling ffmpeg api from Oracle

Tags: oracle, ffmpeg, avi

I have installed ffmpeg and ffmpeg-devel packages on Linux.

Oracle 11g is installed and running.

The database stores media files, and for better streaming we need to convert them to AVI format.

For ease of integration, we would like to do this conversion in the database.

Now, the simplest option is to write a wrapper for the ffmpeg command line utility, and enable a PLSQL procedure to call this.

However this would require the following steps:

1. Read video BLOB
2. Write to a OS file
3. Call ffmpeg wrapper giving file name from (2) and output file name
4. Load output file from 3 into a BLOB in PLSQL

I would like to if possible write a C routine (using the Oracle External Library feature) which accepts the input as the BLOB (OciLOBLocator), calls the appropriate libavformat functions presenting the LOB, and write the return to a LOB (again OciLOBLOcator) which is what the PLSQL layer then uses as the AVI file.

The other advantage of this is it avoids the undesirable impact of issuing a OS command from within Oracle.

The problem I have is that the examples given for ffmpeg show the processing of data from files, whereas I need the libraries to process the LOBs.

The alternative is to see if the OrdVideo data type in Oracle does this kind of conversion by using setformat and process.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting challenge. So it sounds like you would prefer to not have to call the 'ffmpeg' command line utility, but rather leverage the libavformat and libavcodec libraries in native calls within the database. Do I have that right?

I trust that these LOBs/OciLOBLocator things expose a C API for reading and writing? If that's the case, then perhaps you can create a new URLProtocol based on that API. URLProtocols are how FFmpeg deals with I/O. Run 'ffmpeg -protocols' to see all the ones implemented. Examine the source of libavformat/file.c for a simple example of what a URLProtocol entails -- open, read, write, seek, close, and a few other functions.

Comment: Mike, thanks for the response. Yes you are right that is exactly what I want to do. Firing off OS commands from within a DB makes folks nervous, and will be very hard to get passed the DBA police.

I will look at that URL protocol option, and will feed back my findings here.

Comment: Still no useful response to this question.

Comment: You still didn't feed back your findings here. This might be one of those things where you're breaking new ground. Did you try the LOBs/OciLOBLocator option outlined in my answer. I might have tried it but, well... I don't really have an Oracle installation lying around.